# HTML reset button in combination with text field values set with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this form in HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <label for="label-id">id</label>
    <input type="text" name="id" id="label-id" />
    <label for="label-name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="label-name" />
    <label for="label-description">Description</label>
    <input type="text" name="description" id="label-description" />
    <input type="reset" value="Cancel" />
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

There are no values in it, because I set the values with jQuery (AJAX call to a backend system) in this way:

```
$('#label-id').val(data.id);
$('#label-name').val(data.name);
$('#label-description').val(data.description);
```

So, if I press the input type="reset" button, all values are empty. But I want, that pressing on the button the values which I set with the three lines above in jQuery should be there.

For example.
The AJAX call gives me the data id=12, name="test", description="my desc", the values are set to the text input fields and I see these values. Now someone is changing name="test" to "test123". Pressing on the reset button, the value should be name="test" instead of "test123".

How can I do this?

Thank you in advance & Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [`defaultValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533718(v=vs.85).aspx) attribute/property for each `<input>` element, so when the reset button is pushed, all elements are reset to that defined default value:

```
$('#label-id').val(data.id)[0].defaultValue = data.id;
$('#label-name').val(data.name)[0].defaultValue = data.name;
$('#label-description').val(data.description)[0].defaultValue = data.description;
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/NDahF/**

nb: you can just use `.attr("defaultValue", value)` in place of `[0].defaultValue`, but it's not quite as efficient.

Also note that `defaultValue` applies only to text elements.  If you have other types of field you can handle the `<form>` element's [*onreset* event](http://help.dottoro.com/ljnhuwio.php) to re-apply the defaults to selects, checks, radios, etc.

```
$('form').bind("reset", function () {
    $('#label-id').val(data.id);        
    $('#label-name').val(data.name);
    $('#label-description').val(data.description);
    $('#label-someselect').val(data.someSelectValue);

    // Cancel the default action
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't work in older browsers will it? Firefox 2 at least, not sure about IE

Comment: @Nick: it was defined in [DOM level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-html.html#ID-26091157).  It works just fine in IE 6, and I don't think anyone uses Firefox 1 anymore ;-)

Comment: It works in this way, but can you tell me why I need the [0]?

Comment: @Andy - oh no I mean it doesn't work in FF2, it was added in 3 IIRC

Comment: @Tim: see the note at the bottom of the answer.  `[0]` gives us access to the first DOM element within a jQuery object so that we can manipulate its properties directly.  `attr` is somewhat inefficient because it takes the long route to achieve exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Nick: hmm I can't find any documentation on it over at MDC.  I think even Firefox 2 usage is very low these days (hitslink has it at 0.36%).

Comment: @Andy - For other finding this, be wary, it doesn't work for Firefox 2, and only applies to `<input>` and `<textarea>` elements, it won't work on a `<select>` for example, you can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/NDahF/1/

Comment: @Andy - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Property/defaultValue - I tested/confirmed on a VM, Firefox 2 implemented *most* things, that's what makes me wary, but the lack of support of any non-text element is what got me, also doesn't work on checks, radios, etc.

Comment: @Nick: I saw that, but it only applies to XUL elements, so I couldn't be sure.  Confirming with the VM was a good idea :-) Like I said before, Firefox 2 usage is too low to make this a worrying concern, IMO.  I should have mentioned that it only works on text input elements, though.

Answer (score 3):

If you store the data object and make a function of it you can do this, for example:

```
var currentData;
```

Make sure this is outside of everything so it's scoped correctly...e.g. your `ready` handler or even global.  ...and turn the field reset into a function:

```
function resetForm() {
  $('#label-id').val(currentData.id);
  $('#label-name').val(currentData.name);
  $('#label-description').val(currentData.description);
}
```

Then in your `success` handler where you're running the above code, store your `data` (that you're using currently) and run the function we made using it, e.g:

```
currentData = data;
resetForm();
```

Now you can use that same function on the `reset` event of the `<form>` as well, and stop the normal reset, like this:

```
$("form").bind("reset", function(e) {
  resetForm();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```